# How do I flush the input buffer? (C)

Tags: c, flush

Exactly what it says on the tin.  Is there a way for me to empty out the input buffer in preparation for further user input without using the undefined fflush(stdin) or a looped getchar()?

I'm trying to write a small input function that isn't vulnerable to buffer overflows.  For this, I've used fgets(entered_text, 30, stdin); which works as promised.

However, in the event of overflow, I have stuff remaining in the input buffer that gets read when I next call the input function.  I want to empty the buffer to avoid this.

fflush(stdin) is supported, but not defined.  http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html suggests I use a loop of getchars, but the problem is that if the input buffer is empty, it will request a character and force me to press two 'enter's.

Is there a way for me to check if the input buffer is empty, or to empty it by other means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `fgets` can't store all of the data, then the last character will not be '\n' which means you can keep reading more data. I never understood why people think they need to "flush the input buffer" in this situation. It is easy to see if there is more data. Keep reading characters until either a '\n' occurs or EOF. Those are the only two possibilities (otherwise its a normal character).

Comment: This would do the job: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709726/694576

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the input is empty by using `select()`.

Some related information is here: [C select() timeout STDIN single char (no ENTER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514990/c-select-timeout-stdin-single-char-no-enter)

Comment: `select` is POSIX or BSD, not C, and uses file descriptors and not `FILE*`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Use fileno(FILE*) to convert a FILE* to a file descriptor.  select() may not be part of C, but who cares?  It's on every relevant platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fpurge function to clear the buffer stream. Please read the man page of fpurge for more information.

Comment: `fpurge()` is non-standard.