# c TCP chat program, client don't know when to recv

Tags: c, tcpclient

I want to build a chat program, but the problem is that once client sends a message to server, all other client will receive this message from server, but client don't know when the message will come. In the client's main loop it will block on fgets() and wait for user to input a command or message. I need the client program to receive the message and print it while waiting for input from user. How can I do that ?

here's the code:
I haven't write recv for message since I don't know where to put it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LOGIN 1
#define LO_ACK 2
#define LO_NACK 3
#define EXIT 4
#define JOIN 5
#define JN_ACK 6
#define JN_NACK 7
#define LEAVE_SESS 8
#define NEW_SESS 9
#define NS_ACK 10
#define MESSAGE 11
#define QUERY 12
#define QU_ACK 13

struct packet {
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int size;
    char source[20];
    char data[500];
};

int encode(struct packet temp, char *data) {

    sprintf(data, "%d:%d:%s:", temp.type, temp.size,
            temp.source);

    int length = strlen(data);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < temp.size; i++) {
        data[length + i] = temp.data[i];
    }
    data[length + i] = '\0';

    return length;
}

struct packet decode(char *data) {
    int i, j;
    struct packet message;
    char temp[100];
    char source[20];

    sscanf(data, "%d:%d", &message.type, &message.size);

    sprintf(temp, "%d:%d", message.type, message.size);

    int length = strlen(temp);

    for (i = length + 1; data[i] != ':'; i++) {
        message.source[i - length - 1] = data[i];
    }

    for (j = 0; j < message.size; j++) {
        message.data[j] = data[j + i + 1];
    }

    return message;

}

int main(void) {
    int sockfd, numbytes;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    int login = 0;
    char me[20];


    while (1) {
        char buf[500];
        char input[100];
        char *command;
        char arg1[20], arg2[20], arg3[20], arg4[20], arg5[20];
        int i, j, k, l, m;

        fgets(input, 100, stdin);

        if (strlen(input) < 3)
            continue;

        if (input[0] == '/') {//command
            command = &input[1];

            //get first argument
            for (i = 0; command[i] != '\0' && command[i] != ' '; i++) {
                arg1[i] = command[i];
            }
            //arg1[i] = '\0';

            if (strcmp(arg1, "login") == 0) {//login
                //get id,password,ip,port
                if (login == 1) {
                    printf("error: already login\n");
                    continue;
                }

                for (j = i + 1; command[j] != '\0' && command[j] != ' '; j++) {//id
                    arg2[j - i - 1] = command[j];
                }
                //arg1[j-i+1] = '\0';
                for (k = j + 1; command[k] != '\0' && command[k] != ' '; k++) {//password
                    arg3[k - j - 1] = command[k];
                }

                for (l = k + 1; command[l] != '\0' && command[l] != ' '; l++) {//ip
                    arg4[l - k - 1] = command[l];
                }

                for (m = l + 1; command[m] != '\0'; m++) {//port
                    arg5[m - l - 1] = command[m];
                }

                memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
                hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
                hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

                if ((rv = getaddrinfo(arg4, arg5, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
                    return 1;
                }

                for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
                    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
                        perror("client: socket");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                        close(sockfd);
                        perror("client: connect");
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (p == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
                    return 2;
                }

                freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

                struct packet tosend;
                tosend.type = LOGIN;
                sprintf(tosend.data, "%s %s", arg2, arg3);
                strcpy(tosend.source, arg2);
                tosend.size = strlen(tosend.data);

                char message[500];
                encode(tosend, message);

                send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

                usleep(100);
                recv(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                struct packet reply;
                reply = decode(buf);

                if (reply.type == LO_ACK) {
                    printf("login successful\n");
                    strcpy(me, arg2);
                    login = 1;
                    continue;
                } else if (reply.type == LO_NACK) {
                    printf("login failed: %s\n", reply.data);
                    continue;
                }

            } else if (strcmp(arg1, "createsession") == 0) {
                if (login == 0) {
                    printf("error: not login\n");
                    continue;
                }

                for (j = i + 1; command[j] != '\0'; j++) {//session name
                    arg2[j - i - 1] = command[j];
                }

                struct packet tosend;
                tosend.type = NEW_SESS;
                strcpy(tosend.data, arg2);
                strcpy(tosend.source, me);
                tosend.size = strlen(tosend.data);

                char message[500];
                encode(tosend, message);

                send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

                usleep(100);
                recv(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                struct packet reply;
                reply = decode(buf);

                if (reply.type == NS_ACK) {
                    printf("create session successful\n");
                    continue;
                } else if (reply.type == JN_ACK) {
                    printf("session already exist, join session successful\n");
                    continue;
                }
            } else if (strcmp(arg1, "joinsession") == 0) {
                if (login == 0) {
                    printf("error: not login\n");
                    continue;
                }

                for (j = i + 1; command[j] != '\0'; j++) {//session name
                    arg2[j - i - 1] = command[j];
                }

                struct packet tosend;
                tosend.type = JOIN;
                strcpy(tosend.data, arg2);
                strcpy(tosend.source, me);
                tosend.size = strlen(tosend.data);

                char message[500];
                encode(tosend, message);

                send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

                usleep(100);
                recv(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                struct packet reply;
                reply = decode(buf);

                if (reply.type == JN_ACK) {
                    printf("join session successful\n");
                    continue;
                }
            } else if (strcmp(arg1, "leavesession") == 0) {
                if (login == 0) {
                    printf("error: not login\n");
                    continue;
                }

                struct packet tosend;
                tosend.type = LEAVE_SESS;
                strcpy(tosend.data, "none");
                strcpy(tosend.source, me);
                tosend.size = strlen(tosend.data);

                char message[500];
                encode(tosend, message);

                send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

                printf("leave session successful\n");

                continue;
            } else if (strcmp(arg1, "list") == 0) {
                if (login == 0) {
                    printf("error: not login\n");
                    continue;
                }

                struct packet tosend;
                tosend.type = QUERY;
                strcpy(tosend.data, "none");
                strcpy(tosend.source, me);
                tosend.size = strlen(tosend.data);

                char message[500];
                encode(tosend, message);

                send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

                usleep(100);
                recv(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                struct packet reply;
                reply = decode(buf);

                printf("%s", reply.data);

                continue;
            } else {
                printf("invalid command\n");
                continue;
            }

        } else {//message
            if (login == 0) {
                printf("error: not login\n");
                continue;
            }

            struct packet tosend;
            tosend.type = MESSAGE;
            strcpy(tosend.data, input);
            strcpy(tosend.source, me);
            tosend.size = strlen(tosend.data);

            char message[500];
            encode(tosend, message);

            send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);

            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how SO works. You cannot ask us to write code for you. Show your efforts. We can only help if you submit the code.

Comment: where?...please post the code

Comment: There are two options for you. 1) Threads 2) Select. We would have to leave it up to you to read upon them and try to write *code* for them.

Comment: There are also plenty of libraries available for this: libev, libevent, libuv to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

'client don't know when to recv' that's easy: all the time.
There are multiple options:

1) select() on fd's, including stdin (Google for details).

2) poll/epoll() - as above, but improved performance.

3) Have a thread that waits on input and fires messages onto a producer-consumer queue to another 'state-machine' thread that handles those messages, and messages from other threads that handle client recv() data from the server, and performs the required actions.

4) Any other mechanism that might be available from your particular OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

 int main()
 {

    fd_set fds;

    while(1){
        FD_ZERO(&fds); // you NEED to zero this every loop
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
        // add your socket here

        // first argument here will be your socket + 1
        select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds)){
              char buffer[128];
              fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
              printf("User input - stdin: %s", buffer);
        }
        // here check if your socket is set and act accordingly
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

It will read from stdin using select (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), you can use it as a base to study how select works and expand it for your needs.

You will need to add your socket in the fds so it will wait on the select until either there is an user input to process or there is data on your socket (use FD_ISSET to check).

Good luck.

PS: I used the code from this question [Using stdin with select() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219340/using-stdin-with-select-in-c) as a base to produce the one I posted.